# Set the maximum amount of content to be retrieved by Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I want to download the first 16 KB of a given URL and I'm using the GuzzleHTTP library for this. Checking the `Content-Length` header or sending the `Ranges` header will not work for my purposes, since the server may not send/accept any of these headers.

Is there a way I can set the maximum amount of content that should be retrieved by Guzzle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Use [`stream` option](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#stream) to download content by chunks, not all at once.

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/stream/20', ['stream' => true]);
// Read bytes off of the stream until the end of the stream is reached
$body = $response->getBody();
$buffer = '';
while (!$body->eof() && (strlen($buffer) < 16384)) {
    $buffer .= $body->read(1024);
}
$body->close();
```

With this solution you are able to control the amount of content you want to download.

Comment: Isn't there a need to explicitly close the connection? Otherwise, the server would keep sending data...

Comment: Yep, it's better to close the stream with `close()` method. Updated the answer.